# Generate a Bode-form transfer function using ratsimp

Tags: python, sympy, maxima, wxmaxima

I have to simplify a transfer function using sympy. I am used to maxima and I am looking for advice to get similar performances in a python environment.

Using the following Maxima code:

```
A:-Avol0/(1+s/(2*pi*fp));
Zph:Rsh/(1+Rsh*Cj*s);
Zf:Rf/(1+Rf*Cf*s);
alpha:Zf*Zph/(Zf+Zph);
beta:Zph/(Zf+Zph);
BetaA:ratsimp(beta*A,s);
H:ratsimp(alpha*A/(1-BetaA),s);
```

I get the following:

```
(H)-> -(2*Avol0*Rf*Rsh*fp*pi)/((Cj+Cf)*Rf*Rsh*s^2+((2*Cj+(2*Avol0+2)*Cf)*Rf*Rsh*fp*pi+Rsh+Rf)*s+((2*Avol0+2)*Rsh+2*Rf)*fp*pi)
```

The same opertions in sympy do not get to such a nice result:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy

"""
Formulas
"""
s, Rf, Cf, Rsh, Cj, Cd, Ccm, GBP, Avol0, fp, w = \
sy.symbols("s Rf Cf Rsh Cj Cd Ccm GBP Avol0 fp w")

A = -Avol0/(1+s/(2*np.pi*fp))
Zph = Rsh/(1+Rsh*Cj*s)
Zf = Rf/(1+Rf*Cf*s)
alpha = Zf*Zph/(Zf+Zph)
beta = Zph/(Zf+Zph)
Gloop = sy.ratsimp(beta*A)
H = alpha*A/(1-Gloop)
sy.ratsimp(H)
```

returns an unreadable result:

```
-1.0*(1.0*Avol0*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**3 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp*s**4 + 1.0*Avol0*Cf**2*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**2 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cf**2*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp*s**3 + 1.0*Avol0*Cf*Cj**2*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**3 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cf*Cj**2*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp*s**4 + 2.0*Avol0*Cf*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**2 + 0.318309886183791*Avol0*Cf*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp*s**3 + 2.0*Avol0*Cf*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**2 + 0.318309886183791*Avol0*Cf*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp*s**3 + 1.0*Avol0*Cf*Rf**3*Rsh*fp**2*s + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cf*Rf**3*Rsh*fp*s**2 + 2.0*Avol0*Cf*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp**2*s + 0.318309886183791*Avol0*Cf*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp*s**2 + 1.0*Avol0*Cj**2*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**2 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cj**2*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp*s**3 + 2.0*Avol0*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp**2*s + 0.318309886183791*Avol0*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp*s**2 + 1.0*Avol0*Cj*Rf*Rsh**3*fp**2*s + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cj*Rf*Rsh**3*fp*s**2 + 1.0*Avol0*Rf**2*Rsh*fp**2 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Rf**2*Rsh*fp*s + 1.0*Avol0*Rf*Rsh**2*fp**2 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Rf*Rsh**2*fp*s)/(1.0*Avol0*Cf**3*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**4 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cf**3*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp*s**5 + 1.0*Avol0*Cf**3*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**3 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cf**3*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp*s**4 + 1.0*Avol0*Cf**2*Cj**2*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**4 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cf**2*Cj**2*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp*s**5 + 2.0*Avol0*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**3 + 0.318309886183791*Avol0*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp*s**4 + 3.0*Avol0*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**3 + 0.477464829275686*Avol0*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp*s**4 + 1.0*Avol0*Cf**2*Rf**3*Rsh*fp**2*s**2 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cf**2*Rf**3*Rsh*fp*s**3 + 3.0*Avol0*Cf**2*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**2 + 0.477464829275686*Avol0*Cf**2*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp*s**3 + 2.0*Avol0*Cf*Cj**2*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**3 + 0.318309886183791*Avol0*Cf*Cj**2*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp*s**4 + 4.0*Avol0*Cf*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**2 + 0.636619772367581*Avol0*Cf*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp*s**3 + 3.0*Avol0*Cf*Cj*Rf*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**2 + 0.477464829275686*Avol0*Cf*Cj*Rf*Rsh**3*fp*s**3 + 2.0*Avol0*Cf*Rf**2*Rsh*fp**2*s + 0.318309886183791*Avol0*Cf*Rf**2*Rsh*fp*s**2 + 3.0*Avol0*Cf*Rf*Rsh**2*fp**2*s + 0.477464829275686*Avol0*Cf*Rf*Rsh**2*fp*s**2 + 1.0*Avol0*Cj**2*Rf*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**2 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cj**2*Rf*Rsh**3*fp*s**3 + 2.0*Avol0*Cj*Rf*Rsh**2*fp**2*s + 0.318309886183791*Avol0*Cj*Rf*Rsh**2*fp*s**2 + 1.0*Avol0*Cj*Rsh**3*fp**2*s + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Cj*Rsh**3*fp*s**2 + 1.0*Avol0*Rf*Rsh*fp**2 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Rf*Rsh*fp*s + 1.0*Avol0*Rsh**2*fp**2 + 0.159154943091895*Avol0*Rsh**2*fp*s + 1.0*Cf**3*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**4 + 0.318309886183791*Cf**3*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp*s**5 + 0.0253302959105844*Cf**3*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**3*s**6 + 1.0*Cf**3*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**3 + 0.318309886183791*Cf**3*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp*s**4 + 0.0253302959105844*Cf**3*Rf**3*Rsh**2*s**5 + 2.0*Cf**2*Cj**2*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**4 + 0.636619772367581*Cf**2*Cj**2*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp*s**5 + 0.0506605918211689*Cf**2*Cj**2*Rf**3*Rsh**3*s**6 + 4.0*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**3 + 1.27323954473516*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp*s**4 + 0.101321183642338*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh**2*s**5 + 3.0*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**3 + 0.954929658551372*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp*s**4 + 0.0759908877317533*Cf**2*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**3*s**5 + 2.0*Cf**2*Rf**3*Rsh*fp**2*s**2 + 0.636619772367581*Cf**2*Rf**3*Rsh*fp*s**3 + 0.0506605918211689*Cf**2*Rf**3*Rsh*s**4 + 3.0*Cf**2*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**2 + 0.954929658551372*Cf**2*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp*s**3 + 0.0759908877317533*Cf**2*Rf**2*Rsh**2*s**4 + 1.0*Cf*Cj**3*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**4 + 0.318309886183791*Cf*Cj**3*Rf**3*Rsh**3*fp*s**5 + 0.0253302959105844*Cf*Cj**3*Rf**3*Rsh**3*s**6 + 3.0*Cf*Cj**2*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**3 + 0.954929658551372*Cf*Cj**2*Rf**3*Rsh**2*fp*s**4 + 0.0759908877317533*Cf*Cj**2*Rf**3*Rsh**2*s**5 + 4.0*Cf*Cj**2*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**3 + 1.27323954473516*Cf*Cj**2*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp*s**4 + 0.101321183642338*Cf*Cj**2*Rf**2*Rsh**3*s**5 + 3.0*Cf*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh*fp**2*s**2 + 0.954929658551372*Cf*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh*fp*s**3 + 0.0759908877317533*Cf*Cj*Rf**3*Rsh*s**4 + 8.0*Cf*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**2 + 2.54647908947033*Cf*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp*s**3 + 0.202642367284676*Cf*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh**2*s**4 + 3.0*Cf*Cj*Rf*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**2 + 0.954929658551372*Cf*Cj*Rf*Rsh**3*fp*s**3 + 0.0759908877317533*Cf*Cj*Rf*Rsh**3*s**4 + 1.0*Cf*Rf**3*fp**2*s + 0.318309886183791*Cf*Rf**3*fp*s**2 + 0.0253302959105844*Cf*Rf**3*s**3 + 4.0*Cf*Rf**2*Rsh*fp**2*s + 1.27323954473516*Cf*Rf**2*Rsh*fp*s**2 + 0.101321183642338*Cf*Rf**2*Rsh*s**3 + 3.0*Cf*Rf*Rsh**2*fp**2*s + 0.954929658551372*Cf*Rf*Rsh**2*fp*s**2 + 0.0759908877317533*Cf*Rf*Rsh**2*s**3 + 1.0*Cj**3*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**3 + 0.318309886183791*Cj**3*Rf**2*Rsh**3*fp*s**4 + 0.0253302959105844*Cj**3*Rf**2*Rsh**3*s**5 + 3.0*Cj**2*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp**2*s**2 + 0.954929658551372*Cj**2*Rf**2*Rsh**2*fp*s**3 + 0.0759908877317533*Cj**2*Rf**2*Rsh**2*s**4 + 2.0*Cj**2*Rf*Rsh**3*fp**2*s**2 + 0.636619772367581*Cj**2*Rf*Rsh**3*fp*s**3 + 0.0506605918211689*Cj**2*Rf*Rsh**3*s**4 + 3.0*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh*fp**2*s + 0.954929658551372*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh*fp*s**2 + 0.0759908877317533*Cj*Rf**2*Rsh*s**3 + 4.0*Cj*Rf*Rsh**2*fp**2*s + 1.27323954473516*Cj*Rf*Rsh**2*fp*s**2 + 0.101321183642338*Cj*Rf*Rsh**2*s**3 + 1.0*Cj*Rsh**3*fp**2*s + 0.318309886183791*Cj*Rsh**3*fp*s**2 + 0.0253302959105844*Cj*Rsh**3*s**3 + 1.0*Rf**2*fp**2 + 0.318309886183791*Rf**2*fp*s + 0.0253302959105844*Rf**2*s**2 + 2.0*Rf*Rsh*fp**2 + 0.636619772367581*Rf*Rsh*fp*s + 0.0506605918211689*Rf*Rsh*s**2 + 1.0*Rsh**2*fp**2 + 0.318309886183791*Rsh**2*fp*s + 0.0253302959105844*Rsh**2*s**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the maxima code and the python one: const 'pi' is kept symbolic in the first case, and approximated to a floating-point value in the second. Replacing *np.pi* with *pi* solves the problem, anyway it is weird how sympy tries to simplify the expression when pi is numeric.